# Pre-populated values on Chrome autofill are different sizes before selection

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, webkit, autofill

On my app I have multiple forms that ask for basic information from the user (name, email, address, etc).

On Chrome we have the wonderful auto-fill feature. When looking at one of these forms and selecting an auto-fill option, the values get populated with my previously saved information.

However, I've run into a problem. When I hover over the Chrome auto-fill options, my form values are pre-populated (this doesn't bother me, and is preferred). The problem is that these pre-populated values are displayed at a very small font size. Once I select a Chrome auto-fill option, the values are chosen and it jumps from a small font size (of about 8ish px) to what I have it set in my CSS (20px).

I've been looking at the `webkit-autofill` tools... but I feel like I've managed to address everything in a form value except for the actual pre-populated value.

Here are a before image and an after image to illustrate the issue that I'm struggling with here.

[image: before field selection]

[image: after field selection]

My HTML code is:

```html
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputFirst">First Name</label>    <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="exampleInputFirst">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label 
...
```

My CSS code is:

```css
text:-webkit-autofill,
#exampleInputFirst:-webkit-autofill:hover
{
  border: 1px solid red;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

I expected the `font-size: 20px` on the hover would take care of the issue, but it only is going into effect after the value is selected.  Are the pre-populated values able to be formatted in any way?

Comment: Are you sure your CSS selectors are right? For instance, your example code should have a # in front of exampleInputFirst. If that doesn't help, maybe look into the  [text-size-adjust](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-size-adjust)  property.

Comment: Did you ever fix this? I am having the same problem

Comment: @LennyD at the time i had realized that it was coming from chrome itself. Therefore there was nothing I could do with it. I haven't heard if it has been fixed yet, but I imagine if you are running into it, it is likely still happening.